Sending .gz file in HTTP GET RESPONSE
I am trying to write a Server code(Sender) to send a .gz(GZIP) file as part of HTTP GET response.
I need use C++ based solution for this. I am using below approach.
constexpr std::size_t chunk_size = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB chunk size

// Function to read a chunk of data from a file
std::vector<char> readChunk(std::ifstream& file, size_t chunkSize) {
    std::vector<char> buffer(chunkSize);
    file.read(buffer.data(), chunkSize);
    buffer.resize(file.gcount());
    return buffer;
}
// Function to send a chunk of data
void send_chunk(tcp::socket& socket, const std::vector<char>& chunk, std::size_t total_size) {
    http::response<http::string_body> res;
    res.result(http::status::ok);
    res.set(http::field::content_type, "application/octet-stream");
    res.set(http::field::content_length, std::to_string(total_size));
    res.body() = std::string(chunk.data(), chunk.size());
    res.prepare_payload();
    res.set(http::field::content_length, std::to_string(total_size)); http::write(socket, res);
}

// Function to send the file in chunks
void send_file_in_chunks(tcp::socket& socket, const std::string& filename, std::size_t file_size) {
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Read and write the file in chunks
    std::vector<char> chunk;
    do {
        chunk = readChunk(file, chunk_size);
        send_chunk(socket, chunk, file_size);
        file_size -= chunk.size();
    } while (!chunk.empty());
}

This is the main code responsible for sending file:
    
// Determine the size of the file
try{
    std::ifstream file("tcpdump.pcap.gz", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: dummy.gz" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::size_t file_size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::cout << "size of file is" << file_size;
    
    // Send the gzipped file in chunks
    send_file_in_chunks(socket, "tcpdump.pcap.gz", file_size);
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}

Issue:
I have tried different approach to read the .gz files and send it to client.
On the client(receiver) side, some of the .gz files received are corrupt.
Requirement:
Client does not accept the uncompressed file, client is expecting .gz files saved to disk.
Question:
How does a server send the zipped/compressed files, does it uncompress the file and send it, and browser will compress it back and save to disk?

What led you to think that was the way to chunk a large file?  How is the recipient supposed to know the chunks are supposed to be concatenated?

@TimRoberts  Since content-length is set to entire file size, Client(cURL/browser) will wait to receive those many bytes, it will append the data whatever recieved. Should it explicitly mention in the header. Please correct me.

Your send_chunk function does not actually do anything with its socket argument? And even if it did, you are not supposed to send the http header multiple times...

Surely this functionality is already implemented by whatever http framework you are using?

@Botje corrected the code now, I am using boost beast to compose HTTP header and payload. Is reading .gz file like this and sending it over socket valid?

No, you are still emitting multiple headers. Check the boost::beast documentation for http::file_body or copy from the "advanced server" example.
